# Session Disconnecting with reason SESSION_NOT_RELIABLE(4500) in sprinboot stomp websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

We are using Stomp Websocket with internal message broker in springboot service.
In case of multiple users, we are getting many disconnects with error code 4500 leading to issues.

How can we handle this error code so the connection doesn't disconnects.

Comment: where you able to resolve this